# $f$ entire, $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}-0 : f(z) = f(1/z) \rightarrow f$ constant

Tags: complex-analysis

This basically has been answered already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171581/find-all-entire-functions-with-fz-f-frac1z). We want to apply Liouville's theorem and I totally follow the arguments of the second answer. However, 
I just do not see why in the first answer $f$ is bounded on $\{ z: |z| \leq 1 \}$. It is probably super obvious, please enlighten me.

Comment: Because $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Every continuous function from a compact set to $\mathbb C$ is bounded.

Comment: Following the maximum and minimum principle, is it correct that continuous $f$ will indeed attain maximum and minimum on the compact set just like in real analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is holomorphic, hence, continuous. $\{z:|z|\leq 1\}$ is compact. The image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact and, thus, bounded.

This result is known as the [Extreme Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces)

Comment: Thx, cheers! Always forget about implications of compactness..

Comment: Your welcome. :-)

Answer (score 3):

An entire function in a compact set is bounded.